# Redirect in httacess - Delete last part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have some URL's ended with "list-all-products"

I need create redirect to URL without this part.
Etc.:

`domain/eshop/cbd-oel-und-tropfen/list-all-products` to `domain/eshop/cbd-oel-und-tropfen`

`domain/eshop/list-all-products` to `domain/eshop`

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)list-all-products$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ [NC,R=301,L,E=nocache:1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the next rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?list-all-products$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @MrWhite, yes, you're right.